# How can I use Google Analytics to tell what the least busy time of the week is on a website?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, traffic, site-maintenance

I'm needing to do some maintenance on a site, and I'd like to time it for the **least busy time of the week**. I know how to make a custom report to show what the least busy **day** is, as well as what the least busy **hour** of a (generic) day is, but I'm not sure how to combine those two to find the least busy hour of the week.

I know that generally speaking, the least busy day will have the least busy hour, but I'd like to see hard data, y'know?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm wanting to have a report that can basically say "4am on Saturdays" or some such.

EDIT 2: Incidentally, here's why I need the hourly graph to aggregate numbers from multiple weeks:

[image: Jagged graph due to low traffic makes arriving at a conclusion difficult]

The site gets so little traffic that I need multiple weeks to arrive at any sort of meaningful conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to customisation

New custom report (name it if you like!)

Metric groups add page views

Dimensions add hour with a sub level of day of week name.

That should do it!

Edit: I should say when you click in an hour. It will give you the day of the week of name which will give you the right name so reason for the edit as day of the week just gives you 0-6 as the days of the week. (0 = Sunday)

Comment: That works for the raw data, thanks. :) I don't presume there's any way to convert that data into a nice visual graph in Analytics, is there? Just for curiosity's sake... :)

Comment: Yes you can just click in the custom report and next to the search box below the current graph change the display.

Comment: Hmm... those don't seem to do what I'm looking for... ideally, I wanted a graph like what Stephen Ostermiller posted below, but covering multiple weeks aggregated together instead of the single week his covers.

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as pressing the "Hourly" button on the graph after selecting a week's time period.   Then you get something like this:

[image]

You can pick the lowest trough from that graph.  When you mouse over the graph you can see the actual numbers for each hourly data point.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific - I'm wanting to view exactly that kind of graph, but for weekly data aggregated over multiple weeks.